# mysql select distinct n row that has a certain value

Tags: mysql, database

Considering here is my table query:

```
id    name  number   Code
1     red     1       A
2     red     3       B
3     blue    3       C
4     blue    5       A
5     purple  2       D
6     yellow  3       D
7     yellow  4       C
```

Now I need to query to get 2 random row such that there is 1 name is red and 1 number is 3, kinda like this:

**SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "red" LIMIT 1 and number = 3 LIMIT 1**

So like row 1+3,1+6 or 2 + any other row.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
        group by name,number
        having count(name="red") = 1
             and count(number=3) = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

However, it seems like it just query the row randomly and not satisfying my requirement. Can anyone show me what is wrong ?
Thank you.

Comment: What if row 2 was the only row matching the criteria?

Comment: Is it ok to return the same row twice?

Comment: *I need to query to get 2 random row such that there is 1 name is red and 1 number is 3* Is it safe that these 2 random rows occures to be the same row? Is the criteria combination always "one row by `name` and one row by `number`" and criteria values differs only?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. Since row 2 satisfies both the requirement,  the other row does not matter (so 2 + 1/3/4/5/6/7 - whatever is fine). And no duplicate row.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do what you want:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1 
inner join (
  select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
  from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
  on t2.id > t1.id 
  and ('red' in (t1.name, t2.name)) + ('3' in (t1.number, t2.number)) = 2
  order by rand() limit 1
) t2 on t1.id in (t2.id1, t2.id2)
```

Note that the row with the highest probability to be returned is `id = 2`, because it can be combined with any other row of the table.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b4c14c7cf9bbaabf3ac46fa8681ca7a).

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with odd formatting...

```
select x.id x_id
 , x.name x_name
 , x.number x_number
 , x.code x_code
 , y.id y_id
 , y.name y_name
 , y.number y_number
 , y.code y_code
    
   from my_table x
   join my_table y
     on y.id <> x.id
  where x.name = 'red'
    and y.number = 3
 order by rand()
 limit 1;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JmLKq1RwaPrSwS3zx4Qmt/0

Previously, I posted this solution, but it too has some flaws, I think. But TB liked it, so I'll keep it here...

```
select * 
   from my_table where name = 'red'
  union distinct
select * 
   from my_table where number = 3
 order by rand()
 limit 2
```

Comment: Not matched the question. It may return rows where both matches one criteria and none matches another one

Comment: The solution may look like in the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JmLKq1RwaPrSwS3zx4Qmt/1).

Comment: My solution is not safe. Imagine that there is only one row matching 2nd criteria, and at the same time it matches 1st criteria too... if CTE select this row then main query will not add 2nd row, and the output will contain only one row. In the fiddle - comment rows 3 and 6 insertion and execute the query a lot of times - the output may contain either 1 or 2 rows.